# How can I use more than one MatPaginatorIntl provider?

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I have a project which contains several Material tables showing different information - usually in different components, but occasionally I have 2 tables in the same component.

In order to provide a better user experience, I'd like to change the "Items per page" to "XXX per page" on each table, where XXX is whatever the data is (e.g. Projects per page, Parts per page, Samples per page, whatever).

The approved way of providing a custom `MatPaginatorIntl` works fine (if somewhat awkwardly IMHO) if you want a specific language; there appears to be no *official* way to provide a per-paginator "translation" i.e. customisation.

I tried adding a function to my `MatPaginatorIntl` extender:

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material'

export class WGMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {

    itemsPerPageLabel = "Things per page";

    setLabel(label) {
        this.itemsPerPageLabel = `${label} per page`;
    }
}
```

...but then I don't know how to call that function (without the hack below, I do get `Things per page` as expected).

I'm currently using the "secret property" `_intl` to access the label, but I know that's not what you're supposed to do:

```
// This is NOT how you're supposed to do it!
this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = "Projects per page";
```

Does anyone have an elegant, or more official way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [Paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) say that you have to have multiple instances - basically one implementation per `items` type that you want. Here's an example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paginator-intl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapples%2Fapples-paginator.service.ts).

I have two of these Paginator implementations, apples and oranges. Eg. Apples:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplesPaginatorService implements MatPaginatorIntl {
  changes = new Subject<void>();
  // need these or angular complains. You implement them as you need.
  itemsPerPageLabel: string;
  nextPageLabel: string;
  previousPageLabel: string;
  firstPageLabel: string;
  lastPageLabel: string;
  getRangeLabel = () => '';


  setLabel(label) {
    this.itemsPerPageLabel = `${label} per page:`;
    console.log('Changing to this:', this);
    this.changes.next();
  }
}
```

Then in my `ApplesComponent`, I add a provider (private instance just for that component):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-apples',
  templateUrl: './apples.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./apples.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
      useClass: ApplesPaginatorService,
    }]
  })
export class ApplesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginatorIntl) { }

  what = 'Apples';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paginator.setLabel(this.what);
  }
}
```

Note that I injected the regular, MatPaginatorIntl, but provided my custom ApplesPaginator instead in the component metadata.

That is likely not the only way, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try & mark it as accepted answer if it works :) Sorry to be a bit slow responding...